# How can a UITableViewCell change a textLabel text by itself?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

A `UITableViewCell` has a coordinate property `var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

The cell contains an asynchronous function to reverse-geocode the coordinate to a city name. In the function closure the cell should update its `textLabel.text` property with the city name.

This doesn't seem to work.
What works is geocoding in the view controller containing the `tableView` and calling `tableView.reloadData()`.

Is it possible to do this from within the cell without reloading the table data?
(Of course the table view data source gets updated anyway).

Comment: You can reload particular row or section in tableview.

Comment: are you updating textLabel.text on the main thread?

Comment: @Simon Yes, but it doesn't work so I assume it doesn't work without the tableView reloading the cell?

Comment: Look into some asynchronous image downloading in UITableViewCell. Like these https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/ https://www.natashatherobot.com/how-to-download-images-asynchronously-and-make-your-uitableview-scroll-fast-in-ios/  http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/04/27/fastscroll/

It's pretty much the same idea, you're just downloading something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells can update their contents just like any other view. No need to reload the data. However, the problem with having the cell perform this task is the cells are reused. No guarentee on the order of the asynchronous requests.

Instead, use another object to manage the asynchronous requests and data. This object can work with the UITableView to update the cell data as needed. The UIViewController could perform this task.

If you can't get the cell to update itself after a request then it sounds like you have a bug.

Comment: You could have the cell do the request, you'd just need to make sure you ignore its result after `prepareForReuse` is called.

Comment: @bbarnhart Actually it seems that my problem was not that the text would not be set but that the cell would not adapt its height when the `textLabel.text` was set by the async function in the cell. So the `textLabel` was too small to display the text. I think that is the reason why it has to be done on the tableView scope because the tableView needs to be told to redraw the cell to adapt its height. Or do you have any idea how that can be done form inside the cell?

Comment: @Manuel You'll need an instance to the UITableView in the cell to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.  It's truly easier to only decorate the cells from **outside** the cell rather than carrying all the overhead need to update them from within.